# histogram using pandas or searborn

Tags: pandas, histogram, seaborn

let's say I have this data(dataframe from pandas) for example,

```
╔════════════╦═══════╗
║    hour    ║ count ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 10         ║ 1002  ║
║ 11         ║ 1235  ║
║ 12         ║ 12123 ║
║ ....       ║ ....  ║
╚════════════╩═══════╝
```

by this kind of data, how can I plot hisotgram by pandas or seaborn?
(I'd like to plot histogram whose x axis is hour and y axis is frequency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your counts are already calculated, you probably need barplot, not histogram.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'hour':[10, 11, 12], 'count': [1002, 1235, 12123]})
data.plot.bar(x='hour', y='count')
```

[image: barplot example]

Comment: yes, I didn't came up with the idea to use bar chart

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.set_index('hour')['count'].plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]